# Storing json api calls in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, httparty, json-api

I have built an app that consumes a json api.  I removed active record from my app because the data in the api can theoretically change and I don't want to wipe the database each time.

Right now I have a method called self.all for each class that loops through the json creating ruby objects.  I then call that method in various functions in order to work with the data finding sums and percentages.  This all works fine, but seems a bit slow.  I was wondering if there is somewhere I should be storing my .all call rather than instantiating new objects for each method that works with the data.

```
...response was assign above using HTTParty...

def self.all
    puppies = []
    if response.success?
      response['puppies'].each do |puppy|
        accounts << new(puppy['name'],
                        puppy['price'].to_money,
                        puppy['DOB'])
      end
    else
      raise response.response
    end
    accounts
  end

  # the methods below only accept arguments to allow testing with Factories
  # puppies is passed in as Puppy.all

  def self.sum(puppies)
    # returns money object
    sum = Money.new(0, 'USD')
    puppies.each do |puppy|
      sum += puppy.price
    end
    sum
  end

  def self.prices(puppies)
    prices = puppies.map { |puppy| puppy.price }
  end


  def self.names(puppies)
    names = puppies.map { |puppy| puppy.name }
  end

  ....many more methods that take an argument of Puppy.all in the controller....
```

Should I use cacheing?  should I bring back active record? or is how I'm doing it fine? Should I store Puppy.all somewhere rather than calling the method each time?

Comment: If you're open to the idea of using Postgres as a data store, you could take advantage of their JSON data type. More info here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0):

What I guess is happening is that you are making a request with HTTParty every time you call any class method. What you can consider is creating a class variable for the response and a class variable called expires_at. Then you can do some basic caching.

```rb
@@expires_at = Time.zone.now
@@http_response

def make_http_call
  renew_http_response if @@expires_at.past?
end

def renew_http_response
  # make HTTParty request here
  @@http_response = # HTTParty response
  @@expires_at = 30.minutes.from_now
end

# And in your code, change response to @@response
# ie response.success? to @@response.success?
```

This is all in memory and you lose everything if you restart your server. If you want more robust caching, the better thing to do would probably to look into [rails low-level caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching)